# Capistrano: linked file /shared/config/database.yml does not exist on IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger, capistrano3

I don't know if this is a bug or what. But I have my `linked_files` and `linked_dirs` set correctly, I suppose, as in, on `deploy.rb` I have:

```
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'`
```

`cap production deploy:check:linked_dirs` runs successsfully, but 
`cap production deploy:check:linked_files` produces this error => 
`linked file home/deploy/appname/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on IP`, always.

`cap production doctor` prints:

```
:linked_dirs ["log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system", "public/assets"]
:linked_files ["config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"]
```

I have SSH-ed into my server `ssh user@IP` several times so as to confirm if I *have* the database.yml file in the shared/config folder. It is always there and I have even opened it on Vim to confirm. It *does* exist.

I have tried my best to solve this but can't find the solution. Someone help.

```
# deploy.rb
set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/appname'

append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'
```

I have in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7.1', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.2', require: false
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', require: false
```

Comment: Is the lack of a leading slash in `home/deploy/appname…` a transcription typo or part of the path? If the latter, there might be multiple root dirs being used, and you may need to add a prepended slash to the value in `set :deploy_to, "home/deploy/appname"`.

Comment: Note: this originally came from https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1869

Comment: Will, actually, there is no leading slash in the error displayed in the terminal. But I have it in deploy.rb as 'set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/appname''

Comment: What does `cap production doctor` say is the value of `:deploy_to`? Based on the error it seems like your `:deploy_to` is missing the leading slash.

Comment: It gives :deploy_to "home/deploy/graduite". No slash, but when I check deploy.rb file manually in my server, it has the leading slash.

Comment: But I have noticed that I also don't have the slash on my git repo, does it mean that _cap production deploy_ compiles from the repo and not from the files in the server? I had cloned the repo from the server initially, then added the slash from the server.

Comment: `cap` is a program that exists on your local machine. Its configuration is entirely local to your machine. Specifically the `Capfile`, `deploy.rb`, and stage files are all things that must be edited locally.

Comment: Wait a minute, I just corrected my local deploy.rb and included the leading slash at /home then pushed it to git. Run _cap deploy production_ locally and wallas, it worked!  So having a correct version on my server (through the initial cloning) didn't matter as cap fetched the whole thing from my git repo.

Comment: If you change `deploy.rb` locally, that is all you need to do. Pushing that change to your remote git server has no additional effect.

Comment: Thanks @MattBrictson

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your file `database.yml` already on your server?

path example

```
path_to_your_app/shared/config/database.yml
```

And can you show deploy.rb file?

**Update:**

try change these strings

```
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system'
```

to

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system' )
```

Comment: I do have the database.yml file in the path given. And I have posted the deploy.rb above. Kindly check.

Comment: Where did you get this config?
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml'

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might face this in future, make sure you always edit your files on your local machine, not on your server like I did, because in my server's `deploy.rb` file I had the line `set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/appname'`, which is correct, but on my local machine I had `set :deploy_to, 'home/deploy/appname'`, without the leading slash before *home*.

As Matt pointed out in the comments, `cap` is a program that exists on your local machine, so `cap production deploy` will look up capistrano configuration from your local machine and compile the assets from your git repo. So whenever there is anything to change, do so on your local machine and be sure to commit.

Comment: Clarification: the *capistrano configuration* is taken from the local machine. The actual code that is deployed (i.e. your app) is always taken from the remote git repository.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Matt, I've edited the answer